# evaluate multivariate Normal/Gaussian Density in c++

Tags: c++, eigen, normal-distribution

Right now I have the following function to evaluate the Gaussian density:

```
double densities::evalMultivNorm(const Eigen::VectorXd &x, const Eigen::VectorXd &meanVec, const Eigen::MatrixXd &covMat)
{
    double inv_sqrt_2pi = 0.3989422804014327;
    double quadform  = (x - meanVec).transpose() * covMat.inverse() * (x-meanVec);
    double normConst = pow(inv_sqrt_2pi, covMat.rows()) * pow(covMat.determinant(), -.5);
    return normConst * exp(-.5* quadform);
}
```

This is just transcribing the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). However I get a lot of 0, nans and infs. I suspect it's coming from the `covMat.determinant()` portion being very close to zero.

I have heard that it is more "stable" to premultiply `x-meanVec` by the inverse of a "square root" of its covariance matrix. Statistically this gives you a random vector that is mean zero and has the identity matrix as its covariance matrix. My questions are:

1. Is this truly the best way to go?
2. Which is the "best" square root technique, and
3. How do I do it? (Preferably using Eigen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ad 1: "Depends". E.g., if your covariance matrix has a special structure which makes it easy to calculate its inverse or if the dimension is very small, it *can* be faster and more stable to actually calculate the inverse.

Ad 2: Usually, Cholesky decomposition does the job. If your covariance is truly positive definite (i.e., not to close to a semidefinite matrix), decompose `covMat = L*L^T` and compute `squaredNorm(L\(x-mu))` (where `x=A\b` means "Solve `A*x=b` for `x`"). Of course, if your covariance is fixed, you should compute `L` only once (and perhaps invert it as well). You should use `L` to compute `sqrt(covMat.determinant())` as well, since computing the determinant would otherwise require to decompose `covMat` again.
Minor improvement: instead of `pow(inv_sqrt_2pi, covMat.rows())` compute `logSqrt2Pi=log(sqrt(2*pi))` and then return `exp(-0.5*quadform - covMat.rows()*logSqrt2Pi) / L.determinant()`.

Ad 3: This should run in Eigen 3.2 or later:

```
double foo(const Eigen::VectorXd &x, const Eigen::VectorXd &meanVec, const Eigen::MatrixXd &covMat)
{
    // avoid magic numbers in your code. Compilers will be able to compute this at compile time:
    const double logSqrt2Pi = 0.5*std::log(2*M_PI);
    typedef Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> Chol;
    Chol chol(covMat);
    // Handle non positive definite covariance somehow:
    if(chol.info()!=Eigen::Success) throw "decomposition failed!";
    const Chol::Traits::MatrixL& L = chol.matrixL();
    double quadform = (L.solve(x - meanVec)).squaredNorm();
    return std::exp(-x.rows()*logSqrt2Pi - 0.5*quadform) / L.determinant();
}
```

Comment: nice. But is it really more efficient to work directly with L from the cholesky decomposition? I'm facing a similar problem right now and I find it much faster to instead use quadform as (x - mean).transpose() *covMat.llt().solve(x - mean) so far, haven't done a good benchmark though. Can you think of any reason to prefer the square root method (when all that is known about cov_mat is that it is symmetric and psd)?

Comment: @Banana I would be very surprised if your method was faster (to run), since it actually requires the same decomposition but two triangular-solves, instead of  one. Also: how do you compute `sqrt(covMat.determinant())` in your case?

Comment: Why "two" triangular solves? Although you're right, seems weird to get faster runtimes by using the same decomposition. I computed it the exact way you just wrote in the comment. I might do a proper runtime test these days, I might have done something wrong. I was just guessing that the step of retrieving the Cholesky matrix explicitly might for small matrices somehow weigh in.

Comment: `x=llt.solve(b)` essentially does `x=llt.matrixL().solve(b); x=llt.matrixL().transpose().solve(x);` But you are right that computing the decomposition will usually significantly outweigh the cost of doing individual solves. (unless you re-use a decomposition multiple times).