# my imprecise multivariate Normal density

Tags: c++, eigen, probability-density

Is there anything obviously terrible with this function? It will occasionally evaluate to 0.0 when it should instead give me a very small number.

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

typedef Eigen::Matrix< long double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1              > Vec;
typedef Eigen::Matrix< long double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic > Mat;

long double evalMultivNorm(const Vec &x, const Vec &meanVec, const Mat &covMat)
{
    long double quadform  = (x - meanVec).transpose() * covMat.inverse() * (x-meanVec);
    long double normConst = pow(inv_sqrt_2pi, covMat.rows()) * pow(covMat.determinant(), -.5);
    return normConst * exp(-.5* quadform);
}
```

Comment: Two things: You compute the inverse of your covariance matrix in every call of evalMultivNorm, while you could do that only once and just pass the inverse matrix as an argument (the same holds for covMat.determinant()). You could also improve your numerical stability by decomposing the covariance matrix, i.e. using the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), which works perfectly for covariance matrices. Eigen already supports it, as far as I know. Or you could try something similar to [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [evaluate multivariate Normal/Gaussian Density in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538095/evaluate-multivariate-normal-gaussian-density-in-c)